# external scripts build.phonegap 3.1.0

Tags: google-maps, cordova

I'm having trouble getting by Android build.phonegap app to load in external scripts (google maps specifically). I have had this issue for several days now and tried so many possible solutions.

I have built a very simple one page app that calls and displays a google map.
I run this in my browser and all is well. 
After I run the app through the build.Phonegap it fails to load the external google map in the device(google nexus).

Any help would be great!

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
        <script src="phonegap"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "org.fifedirect.mapapp"
    versionCode="1"
    version   = "1.0.0">
    <name> My Map APP</name>
    <description>
        Test to check if maps are working       
    </description>
    <author href="" email="steven.gardner-crm@fife.gov.uk">
        Steven Gardner
    </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="5000" />
    <preference name="load-url-timeout" value="20000" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"  />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look correct:

```
<script src="phonegap"></script>
```

Have you tried installing this to a 4.4 emulator and debugging it with the Chrome DevTools through 'chrome://inspect'?

Info: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews